# Update statement to change all values in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query that will update all values the values in the Values column.

This is what I've come up with:

```
Begin
    UPDATE Order_Details
    SET Value = (Value / 100) * 10
    WHERE Cust_Ref = ALL
End
```

It doesn't work and comes up with

`Incorrect syntax near keyword END`

Does anyone know how to correct this?

Thanks guys! Much appreciated!!!

Comment: What is Cust_Ref = ALL doing?  Either you want all Cust_Refs or one called 'ALL'.  I suspect ALL is reserved.

Comment: Cust_Ref = All: as in set all the rows in the Value column to the equation in the Set command.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `Where` clause

```
UPDATE Order_Details SET Value = (Value / 100.0) * 10
```

You need to use `Where` clause only when you want to filter the records

Also `Value / 100` will do a `Integer` division. The decimal values will not be present in result. So make either the `numerator` or `denominator` as `decimal` value

**Example :**

```
select 1/ 10  -- Result 0
select 1/ 10.0 -- Result 0.100000
```

Comment: Even if that was a conditional update.. syntax error near End was due to missing quotes '' around the `varchar` value ALL.

Comment: @nikhilvartak - there is a `BEGIN` before `update` did you check that